# How do I prevent a model callback from being triggered if an association callback is triggered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `PositionGroup` that `has_many :positions`.

Whenever a position is added or saved, I want it to update an attribute on `PositionGroup`. E.g. when a new position has been added to a `PositionGroup`, I would like to add the `position.volume` to the existing `position_group.total_units`.

So, consider the following example:

```
pg.total_units = 100 
position2.volume = 50 
# then pg.total_units should be updated to:
pg.total_units = 150
```

I realize I can do this with an association callback and that’s fine.

The issue is, what happens when I want to update a previous position’s volume. If I add a `before_save` or an `after_save`, then that callback will also be triggered after the `after_add` callback is triggered -- thereby artificially inflating the `pg.total_units` figure.

How do I solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by previous position's volume.
Do you want the callback to be triggered only for newly created records?

Comment: @Surya I figured out a solution and added my answer. Thanks though!

Comment: I would really just setup a database trigger to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

Basically, rather than using many `after_save, before_save & after_add` callbacks, I am just using `touch: true` on one model and a `after_touch` on the other. That solved all of my problems.

For more clarity, on my `Position` model, I added:

```
belongs_to :position_group, touch: true
```

Then on my `PositionGroup` model, I added:

```
after_touch :recompute_total_units

  private

  def recompute_total_units
    update_column(:total_units, positions.sum(:volume))
  end
```

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, here's one naive way to prevent that artificial inflation:

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position_group
  before_save :update_position_group_total_units

  def update_position_group_total_units
    delta = volume - (volume_was || 0)
    position_group.update!(total_units:  position_group.total_units + delta)
  end
end
```

```
class PositionGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions
end
```

See documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

*The caveat being, if the save fails for some reason, position_group will still update resulting in a different kind of miscalculation.*

**I like the touch approach best**, as you discovered:

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position_group, touch: true
end
```

```
class PositionGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions

  after_touch :recompute_total_units

  private

  def recompute_total_units
    update_column(:total_units, positions.sum(:volume))
  end
end
```