# Is there a simple way to calculate sumproduct in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `PositionGroup` that `has_many :positions`.

Whenever a `position_group` object is touched, I would like to update `pg.average_price` like so:

```
# Average Price = ((position1.transaction_price * (position1.volume/total_volume) + 
# position2.transaction_price * (position2.volume/total_volme))
```

In my callback method, I tried this:

```
  def update_average_price
    total_volume = positions.sum(:volume)
    avg_price = positions.sum("transaction_price * (volume/#{total_volume})")
    update_column(:average_price, avg_price)
  end
```

But when I check the value of `avg_price` once multiple `positions` exist, I am getting `0.0`.

This is my spec for this specific functionality:

```
it "should calculate the Weighted Average Purchase Price of all positions" do
  # Position 3: Price = 20, volume = 200
  # (Position 1 Price * (Position 1 Units/Total # of Units)) +
  # (Position 2 Price * (Position 2 Units/Total # of Units)) +
  # (Position 3 Price * (Position 3 Units/Total # of Units))
  # ($10 * (100/400)) + ($15 * (100/400) + $20 * (100/400)) =
  # ($2.50 + $3.75 + $5) = $11.25
  price3 = 20
  pos3 = create(:position, stock: stock, portfolio: portfolio, transaction_price: 20, current_price: price3, action: :buy, volume: 200, position_group: pg)
  expect(pg.average_price).to eql 11.25
end
```

This is the result when I run it:

```
1) PositionGroup methods should calculate the Weighted Average Purchase Price of all positions
     Failure/Error: expect(pg.average_price).to eql 11.25

       expected: 11.25
            got: 0.0

       (compared using eql?)
```

I am pretty sure the issue is this line, from my callback method `update_average_price` on `PositionGroup`:

```
avg_price = positions.sum("transaction_price * (volume/#{total_volume})")
```

Is there a better way to approach this or is there something else giving me that `0.0` when I shouldn't be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
avg_price = positions.sum("transaction_price * (volume/#{total_volume.to_f})")
```

`to_f` is missing, converting to float to get a decimal to work with.

Example

```
irb(main):022:0> Position.all
  Position Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Position id: 1, transaction_price: 0.5e2, volume: 150, position_group_id: 1>, #<Position id: 2, transaction_price: 0.1e1, volume: 50, position_group_id: 1>]>
irb(main):023:0> Position.all.sum("transaction_price * (volume/#{total_volume.to_f})")
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM(transaction_price * (volume/200.0)) FROM "positions"
=> 37.75
```

Comment: Perfect. You are correct. That's exactly what it was. Thanks much man!

Comment: Quick question, did you create a `Position` model in a Rails app to get that IRB output? Or did you fake it? If you faked it, how? Manually?

Comment: I created a `Position` and `PositionGroup` model and appropriate migrations in a dummy Rails app (mostly carryover from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795785/how-do-i-prevent-a-model-callback-from-being-triggered-if-an-association-callbac/60797008#60797008)

Comment: A separate tip: in a separate SQL runner or using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` you can run any SQL. In this case you can see the SQL generated by ActiveRecord and test that out separately. Once you get it working in SQL, you can convert back to ActiveRecord!